# GCP k8s pod can not access TLS enabled GCP Redis Memorystore

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a pod in Kubernetes cluster in GCP (GKE) that cannot connect to Memorystore(Redis). They are both on the same authorized network and VPC-native traffic routing(alias IP) is enabled for that cluster. In-transit encryption is enabled for the memorystore but auth is disabled. I have tried two ways to make it work:

**First way:** I downloded the TLS Certificate Authority certificate from GCP and added that as a configmap in the same namespace as my pod and passed that to volume mounts this way in my deployment yaml file of the pod:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/server-ca.pem
          subPath: server-ca.pem
          name: memorystorecert
          readOnly: false  
      volumes:
      - name: memorystorecert
        configMap:
          name: memorystorecert
```

That doesn't seem to be working.

**Second way:** I installed stunnel4 in the Dockerfile of my application this way:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y stunnel4 
CMD ["stunnel4", "/etc/stunnel/server-ca.pem"]
```

and passed the pem cert to the container using mountpath in the deployment.yaml of the pod:

```
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: REDIS_HOST
      value: localhost

    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/stunnel/server-ca.pem
      subPath: server-ca.pem
```

Can someone guide me if I'm doing any of these ways wrong?

Comment: have you checked this troublshooting guidelines by Google? https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/troubleshooting

Comment: yes that didn't help though. I'm figuring out the resolution and will update here as soon as I can make it work.

Comment: ok, while doing that I've also found this Github topic. https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7687

Comment: Thanks! That's not the case for me though.

Comment: @atefeh Did you get it working? If so, can you please share the solution ?

Comment: @RamyaKaruna oh sorry I didn't add the answer here. I ended up asking one of our seniors to help me with that, I'll add it in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as answer but I take no credit for it. So the Dockerfile should be having this part to copy over the certificate and substitute the configs to the container in the right places ( replace *. *. *. *  in the configs with Primary Endpoint of your GCP redismemorystore):

```
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y stunnel
COPY ./stunnel/redis-cli.conf /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf
COPY ./stunnel/server-ca.pem /etc/stunnel/server-ca.pem
RUN sed -i 's@output=.*@output=/dev/stdout@' /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf  &&\
    sed -i 's@CAfile=.*@CAfile=/etc/stunnel/server-ca.pem@' /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf  &&\
    sed -i 's@accept=.*@accept=127.0.0.1:6378@' /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf  &&\
    sed -i 's@connect=.*@connect=*.*.*.*:6378@' /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and the entrypoint.sh should be having this to run stunnel4 in the background. You probably want to run stunnel in the background if this isn't the main process of the container, since if you don't do it like that, stunnel will probably take the foreground and your application will never start:

```
stunnel /etc/stunnel/redis-cli.conf &
```

And you then need to have a stunnelfolder beside your Docker file and have the two files redis-cli.conf and server-ca.pem. server-ca.pem is the The server Certificate Authority (CA) of your redis memoystore and you can find that in the security tab of your memorystore instance and download it there. Your redis-cli.conf should have ( replace *. *. *. *  in the configs with Primary Endpoint of your GCP redismemorystore) :

```
output=/tmp/stunnel.log
CAfile=/tmp/server-ca.pem
client=yes
pid=/var/run/stunnel.pid
verifyChain=yes
sslVersion=TLSv1.2
debug=debug
[redis]
accept=127.0.0.1:6378
connect=*.*.*.*:6378
```

And this would be in your pod deployment's configs:

```
    - mountPath: /etc/stunnel/server-ca.pem
      name: memorystorecert
      subPath: server-ca.pem
```

and this as well

```
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: memorystorecert
    name: memorystorecert
```